# Sending Request via Postman works fine but not via angular client

Tags: angular, ajax, get, postman

my Setup:

Web-API implemented in .Net Core 3.1.

Angular12 Frontend.

My API has an Endpoint that, when requested with the email address of user, searches in my Active Directory and returns the **fullName** of that user.
Then I want to display that name in a component in angular.

It works perfectly with **Postman**, I get the name of the user as **text**
[image]

As you can see there are **no custom headers and no query params** attached to that Get Request that I make.

So I thought I could implement the same in angular.
I added:

```
    getFullName() {
    this.http.get<string>('https://localhost:44316/api/ADInfo/maid.sabanovic@gws.ms').subscribe(Response => {
      this.fullName = Response;
      console.log(this.fullName);
    });
  }
```

And I get:

[image]

Also the FullName Variable is **undefined**

Are there big Differences when sending Requests via Postman and via Angular?
Do I need to add headers to my request?

Comment: Can you show me the request in your network on your browser console please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return Non-Json data, you need to pass {responseType: 'text'} in your request header.

```
getFullName() {
this.http.get<string>('https://localhost:44316/api/ADInfo/maid.sabanovic@gws.ms', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(Response => {
  this.fullName = Response;
  console.log(this.fullName);
});
}
```